# Loop not breaking

Tags: python

So I have a python program that has multiple possible inputs, for this part, I am trying to break out of the while loop that asks "enter a product cost" however, when the user inputs a valid cost, it just reprompts them to enter another cost instead of ending.

```
while True:
    update_choice = input("What would you like to update? (c)ost or (q)uantity")
    if update_choice == "c":
    while True:
        new_price_update = float(input("Enter a product cost: "))
        if new_price_update > 0:
            for i in range(0, len(product_names)):
                if update_item == product_names[i]:
                    product_costs[i] = new_price_update
                    print("Product cost has been updated.")
                    break
                else:
                    print("Invalid price. Please try again.")
```

Comment: What is `product_names`?

Comment: `break` only breaks the current loop, which is `for i ...` in your case.

Comment: `break` is inside the `for` loop, Python only breaks out of one level of nesting at a time. You could set a variable then break from the for loop and then break again if the variable is true.

Answer (score 0):

`break` only exit the current loop. Since you break in the inner most for loop, this only exit this one. You end up in the second while loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
while True:
        new_price_update = float(input("Enter a product cost: "))
        if new_price_update > 0:
            for i in range(0, len(product_names)):
                if update_item == product_names[i]:
                    product_costs[i] = new_price_update
                    print("Product cost has been updated.")
                break
```

You are using a double loop statement : 
`while True:` and `for i in range...`.

The break statement will only exit the innermost loop it is in, the `for` loop, but will continue to loop inside the `while True:` loop, prompting the user again.

Try this instead :

```
while True:
        new_price_update = float(input("Enter a product cost: "))
        if new_price_update > 0:
            for i in range(0, len(product_names)):
                if update_item == product_names[i]:
                    product_costs[i] = new_price_update
                    print("Product cost has been updated.")
                    break
            break
```

Answer (score 0):

Insert another `break` to stop the inner `while True:`, cause your `break` statement will only stop the `for` one, like this:

```
while True:
    update_choice = input("What would you like to update? (c)ost or (q)uantity")
    if update_choice == "c":
    while True:
        new_price_update = float(input("Enter a product cost: "))
        if new_price_update > 0:
            for i in range(0, len(product_names)):
                if update_item == product_names[i]:
                    product_costs[i] = new_price_update
                    print("Product cost has been updated.")
                    break
                else:
                    print("Invalid price. Please try again.")
            break
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `break` will only 'break' out of the inner for loop. to break out of the 2nd while loop, you'll need to place the `break` outside of the for loop.

```
    while True:
        update_choice = input("What would you like to update? (c)ost or (q)uantity")
        if update_choice == "c":
            while True:
                new_price_update = float(input("Enter a product cost: "))
                if new_price_update > 0:
                    for i in range(0, len(product_names)):
                        if update_item == product_names[i]:
                            product_costs[i] = new_price_update
                            print("Product cost has been updated.")
                    break
                else:
                    print("Invalid price. Please try again.")
```

Answer (score 0):

If upon user updating `cost` successfully, you want to break out of the whole process, try this code instead:

```
# while loop (1)
while True:
    # flag to indicate updated successfully
    updated = False

    update_choice = input("What would you like to update? (c)ost or (q)uantity")

    if update_choice == "c":

        # while loop (2)
        while True:
            new_price_update = float(input("Enter a product cost: "))
            if new_price_update > 0:

                # for loop (1)
                for i in range(0, len(product_names)):
                    if update_item == product_names[i]:
                        product_costs[i] = new_price_update
                        print("Product cost has been updated.")

                        updated = True
                        # break out from for loop (1)
                        break
            else:
                print("Invalid price. Please try again.")

            if (updated == True):
                # break out from while loop (2)
                break

        if (updated == True):
            # break out from while loop (1)
            break
```